# is there any way to read multiple data alerts in power bi, using flow, or some other way?

Tags: powerbi, azure-logic-apps, power-automate, adaptive-cards

is there a way to read data alerts in power bi using some sort of python code or something else? i want to be able to gather multiple data alerts for a specified account, then integrate them into an adaptive card.

flow doesn't seem to be able to do this for me, using flow i would need to create multiple flow apps to read one at a time and then somehow write the data somewhere that i can read later. this creates a availability problem for me, since i wouldn't want to be creating a new flow app every time i have a new powerbi alert.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can read multiple data alerts in one logic app/power-automate if you use "[When a HTTP request is received](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres#add-request-trigger)" as the trigger of the flow. You can specify the required data for multiple data alerts as the request body of the request.

For example, you set the "**When a HTTP request is received**" trigger as POST method. And then define the request body json schema for the data you want to input.
[image]

Then you can use the data which input in the request body in your python code to gather multiple data alerts.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late response, how would i make the power bi alert send its data to a specified URL so i can capture it? im a bit new to using Logic-Apps so any help is appreciated.